# How to perform an action on each imploded value?

Tags: php, arrays

I do not have a real use case but am simply wondering if this is possible and how i should do it.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
$array = array('1234', '5678', '9101', '1121', '3141');
```

And I would like to implode that.

```
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Let's say I would like to perform an action on the `values` before they get implodes. For example reversing the string using `strrev()`. How would I go about this?

### Edit

I will try to explain it a little better.

```
$array = range('a', 'z');

// I know this is not possible    
$string = implode(', ', strtoupper($array));

// Desired output : A, B, C, D ...
```

I am wondering if it can be done using `array_map()` but ain't good in working with that function.

Comment: have you tried something? what is your desired output, please paste here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map` function should work fine for built-in and "custom" functions(as a first argument of the function):

```
$array = array('1234', '5678', '9101', '1121', '3141');
$string = implode(', ', array_map("strrev", $array));

print_r($string);  // "4321, 8765, 1019, 1211, 1413"
```

---

Another approach:

```
function addSeparator($word, $char = "-") {
    $words = str_split($word, 2);
    return implode($char, $words);
}
$string = implode(', ', array_map("addSeparator", $array));

print_r($string);  // "12-34, 56-78, 91-01, 11-21, 31-41"
```

Comment: Didn't know it was this simple. I was trying `implode(',', array_map(function () {}))` :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply do your logic before imploding:

```
$array = array('1234', '5678', '9101', '1121', '3141');

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = strrev($value);
}

$string = implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid foreaches. Can it be done using `array_map`?

Comment: @Peter Yes, you can use `array_map`